# Detect if a Flash video is playing or not

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, video

I have a *NetConnection* attached to a *NetStream*, which is in turn attached to a *Video*. As you can guess, this is a video player. I've looked through the public properties of all three classes and could not find an "isPlaying" property - a boolean that would tell me video is currently running (and not paused, stopped, nor corrupted). Does such a property exist? I've tried the following but they don't work:

- *return this.video.currentFPS > 0*. The FPS is around 25 even when the
  video is paused.
- Listen on
  *NetStatusEvent* change and update my own private isPlaying property accordingly. The
  NetStatus does not change when you pause the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `Timer` to check your `stream.time` and compare it to the previous value. writing a custom `togglePause()` function and storing the state in some private variable'd also be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can see the docs for the [`Video`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html) and [`NetStream`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html) elements, which you'll note neither have an `isPlaying` property.

You can check out the `VideoPlayer` class's code (probably at `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\FLVPlayback\fl\video` if you left the default install and use windows) to see an example of how to manage the play states, just don't copy the code as it's a scrambled mess.

tl;dr: **you have to manage the video's state yourself**